# Prevent abuse of an PHP Joomla controller

Tags: php, security, joomla, token

I had a request from a client who wants a quotation form on their website. Their website is build / running on top of Joomla 3 and the forms are build with RSForm. The form contains an postal / ZIP code and house number field.

My client's requirement is, when the postal / ZIP code and house number input fields are filled in, the street and city fields are automatically filled in based on the postal/zip code and number.

After a bit of research and comparing, I found a specific API that fulfills my client's needs. This API however is not free, and is limited a certain amount of calls each minute, with a certain payment yearly.  This API requires an key which each request.

I made the quotation form using RSForm and included a Javascript event listeners to it. When the postal / ZIP code and house number field are filled in, and both fields are valid, it calls an AJAX / XMR HTTP request to an PHP file which calls the API (with CURL) with the key to retrieve the data I want. This way the key is not visible on the front-end. After the data is received the street and city fields are filled.

This however leaves the PHP file / controller open for everybody. The key is not visible, but everybody could and use the URL to do the requests.

For example (legit user):

- Visitor visits the form and fills in their details.
- Javascript detect valid postal/zipcode and sends GET request to website.com/media/postalcode/postalcode.php
- Postalcode.php returns valid or invalid address (call costs money)
- Javascript gets JSON answer and updates form/page

For example (mischievous user):

- Mischievous user visits the form and fills in details.
- Javascript detect valid postal/zipcode and sends GET request to website.com/media/postalcode/postalcode.php
- Mischievous user catches GET request to specific URL (PHP script)
- Mischievous user uses this URL to validate his/hers input data for "free"

The key is not visible, but every visitor could figure out sending postalcodes/zipcodes to this file/url to retrieve the data they want, and my client would be charged for it.

How can I prevent abuse of this URL? I would like my PHP file only to call the API when the form is edited / filled in, but not when a external mischievous user is just abusing it by accessing it by URL with the parameters / request body, bypassing the need for a own key.

Is it possible for my PHP script to detect when a user is legit filling the form, which retrieves information and auto fills the remaining fields?
Or when the request comes from an external source trying to get free address information, it doesn't call the API but responds with 'not allowed'?

First thing I tried was comparing the URI from the request. To make sure the PHP script is called only when filling out the form. But an person can easily fool this URI.

I tried implementing an (X)CORS token on the form, but a bad person could redirect each request from his own to my form, catch the token, and then do the GET call to my PHP form.

Comment: Try asking Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: RSForms supports several CAPTCHA technologies, utilizing those should thwart most attempts, automated at least.